# how to connect to imap through socks ? Go

Tags: go, socks

I'm trying to connect to an IMAP server through a [socks5](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.net/proxy#SOCKS5). To do so I've exported some functions from the [Imap](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go-imap/go1/imap#DialTLS) package but I got stuck at the socks5 dialer setup(1st step:) .
  I think the reason is that I'm passing  `nil` as `forward` (of type `Dial`) argument . What is the `forward` argument supposed to be ? It is not documented (in godoc)

```
func dialSocks(socks string) (Dial proxy.Dialer, err error) {
    Dial, err = proxy.SOCKS5("tcp", socks, nil, nil)
    return
}

func dialTLS(addr string, config *tls.Config) (c *imap.Client, err error) {
    addr = defaultPort(addr, "993")
    d, err := dialSocks("101.120.113.185:1328")
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
        return
    }
    conn, err := d.Dial("tcp", addr)
    if err == nil {
        host, _, _ := net.SplitHostPort(addr)
        tlsConn := tls.Client(conn, setServerName(config, host))
        if c, err = imap.NewClient(tlsConn, host, 60*time.Second); err != nil {
            conn.Close()
        }
    }
    return
}

func defaultPort(addr, port string) string {
    _, _, err := net.SplitHostPort(addr)
    if err != nil {
        addr = net.JoinHostPort(addr, port)
    }
    return addr
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forward` is the `Dialer` used to connect to the proxy.

You can use `proxy.Direct` here if you want (which is the default within the package, if you look at the source), but all that is doing is delegating to `net.Dial(network, addr)`. If you want more options, insert your own Dialer.